# Compilation Error on Algorand Smart Contract TEAL Template Examples

Tags: compiler-errors, blockchain, smartcontracts

I am trying to deploy sample TEAL contracts provided in the following GitHub repository.

[TEAL Templates](https://github.com/algorand/go-algorand/tree/master/tools/teal/templates)

I am able to compile the TEAL example - HTLC from this repository. However I am getting compilation error while I am trying to compile the following ASA contracts. Initially I tried connecting to MainNet and then to the TestNet. Both the cases, I am facing compilation errors.

[Split TEAL Template](https://github.com/algorand/go-algorand/tree/master/tools/teal/templates/split.teal)

[Delegate Key Registraion TEAL Template](https://github.com/algorand/go-algorand/blob/master/tools/teal/templates/delegate-key-registration.teal.tmpl)

Can anybody share some pointers on this error. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this Algorand Smart Contract Compilation Error by setting pre-defined values for all the mentioned variables and parameters in the TEAL contracts. For example, TMPL_FEE may be set to 10000. It is working fine now.